# Combine rows (under a condition) in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe (df) (orginally from a excel file) and the first 9 rows are like this:

```
      Control      Recd_Date/Due_Date                Action        Signature/Requester
0     2000-1703   2000-01-31 00:00:00           OC/OER/OPA/PMS/                 M WEBB
1           NaN   2000-02-29 00:00:00                       NaN              DATA CORP
2     2000-1776   2000-01-02 00:00:00            OC/ORA/OE/DCP/                  G KAN
3           NaN   2000-01-03 00:00:00           OC/ORA/ORO/PNC/              PALM POST
4           NaN                   NaN  FDA/OGROP/ORA/SE-FO/FLA-                    NaN
5           NaN                   NaN                DO/FLA-CB/                    NaN
6     2000-1983   2000-02-02 00:00:00  FDA/OGROP/ORA/CE-FO/CHI-                 M EGAN
7           NaN   2000-02-03 00:00:00                DO/CHI-CB/   BERNSTEIN LIEBHARD &
8           NaN                   NaN                       NaN             LONDON LLP
```

- Type(df['Control'][1])=float;
- Type(df['Recd_Date/Due_Date'][1])=datetime.datetime;
- type(df['Action_Office'][1])=float;
- Type(df['Signature/Requester'][1])=unicode

I want to transform this dataframe (e.g. first 9 rows) to this:

```
      Control            Recd_Date/Due_Date                           Action                                                            Signature/Requester
0     2000-1703   2000-01-31 00:00:00,2000-02-29 00:00:00           OC/OER/OPA/PMS/                                                      M WEBB,DATA CORP
1     2000-1776   2000-01-02 00:00:00,2000-01-03 00:00:00           OC/ORA/OE/DCP/OC/ORA/ORO/PNC/FDA/OGROP/ORA/SE-FO/FLA-DO/FLA-CB/      G KAN,PALM POST
2     2000-1983   2000-02-02 00:00:00,2000-02-03 00:00:00           FDA/OGROP/ORA/CE-FO/CHI-DO/CHI-CB/                                   M EGAN,BERNSTEIN LIEBHARD & LONDON LLP
```

So basically:

- Everytime pd.isnull(row['Control']) (This should be the only if condition) is true then merge this row with the previous row (whose 'control' value is not null).
- And for 'Recd_Date/Due_Date' and 'Signature/Requester', add ',' (or '/') between each two values (from two merged rows) (e.g. '2000-01-31 00:00:00,2000-02-29 00:00:00' and 'G KAN,PALM POST')
- For 'Action', simply merge them without any punctuations added (e.g. FDA/OGROP/ORA/CE-FO/CHI-DO/CHI-CB/)

Can anyone help me out pls? This is the code im trying to get it to work:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(df.ix[i]['Control_#']):
       df.ix[i-1]['Recd_Date/Due_Date'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Recd_Date/Due_Date'])+'/'+str(df.ix[i]['Recd_Date/Due_Date'])
       df.ix[i-1]['Subject'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Subject'])+' '+str(df.ix[i]['Subject'])
       if str(df.ix[i-1]['Action_Office'])[-1] == '-':
           df.ix[i-1]['Action_Office'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Action_Office'])+str(df.ix[i]['Action_Office'])
       else:
           df.ix[i-1]['Action_Office'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Action_Office'])+','+str(df.ix[i]['Action_Office'])
       if pd.isnull(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester']):
           df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])+str(df.ix[i]['Signature/Requester'])
       elif str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])[-1] == '&':
           df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])+' '+str(df.ix[i]['Signature/Requester'])
       else:
           df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])+','+str(df.ix[i]['Signature/Requester'])
       df.drop(df.index[i])
```

How come the drop() doesn't work? I am trying drop the current row (if its ['Control_#'] is null) so the next row (whose ['Control_#'] is null) can be added to the previous row (whose ['Control_#'] is NOT null) iteratively..

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Have you looked at the shift method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081878/get-previous-rows-value-and-calculate-new-column-pandas-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to group the rows together and then join up the column values.  The tricky part is finding a way to group together the rows in the way you want.  Here is my solution...

#### 1) Grouping Together the Rows: Static variables

Since your groups depend on a sequence in your rows I used a static variable in a method to label every row to a specific group

```
def rolling_group(val):
    if pd.notnull(val): rolling_group.group +=1 #pd.notnull is signal to switch group
    return rolling_group.group
rolling_group.group = 0 #static variable
```

This method is applied along the Control series to sort indexes into groups, which is then used to split up the dataframe to allow you to merge rows

```
#groups = df.groupby(df['Control'].apply(rolling_group),as_index=False)
```

That is really the only tricky part after that you can just merge the rows by applying a function to each group that gives you your desired output

## Full Solution Code

```
def rolling_group(val):
    if pd.notnull(val): rolling_group.group +=1 #pd.notnull is signal to switch group
    return rolling_group.group
rolling_group.group = 0 #static variable

def joinFunc(g,column):
    col =g[column]
    joiner = "/" if column == "Action" else ","
    s = joiner.join([str(each) for each in col if pd.notnull(each)])
    s = re.sub("(?<=&)"+joiner," ",s) #joiner = " "
    s = re.sub("(?<=-)"+joiner,"",s) #joiner = ""
    s = re.sub(joiner*2,joiner,s)    #fixes double joiner condition
    return s
```

**#edit above - str(each) - to convert to strings...
edit above regex to clean join string joins**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = """      Control      Recd_Date/Due_Date                Action        Signature/Requester
0     2000-1703   2000-01-31 00:00:00           OC/OER/OPA/PMS/                 M WEBB
1           NaN   2000-02-29 00:00:00                       NaN              DATA CORP
2     2000-1776   2000-01-02 00:00:00            OC/ORA/OE/DCP/                  G KAN
3           NaN   2000-01-03 00:00:00           OC/ORA/ORO/PNC/              PALM POST
4           NaN                   NaN  FDA/OGROP/ORA/SE-FO/FLA-                    NaN
5           NaN                   NaN                DO/FLA-CB/                    NaN
6     2000-1983   2000-02-02 00:00:00  FDA/OGROP/ORA/CE-FO/CHI-                 M EGAN
7           NaN   2000-02-03 00:00:00                DO/CHI-CB/   BERNSTEIN LIEBHARD &
8           NaN                   NaN                       NaN             LONDON LLP"""
    df =  pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(df),sep = "\s\s+",engine='python')

    groups = df.groupby(df['Control'].apply(rolling_group),as_index=False)
    groupFunct = lambda g: pd.Series([joinFunc(g,col) for col in g.columns],index=g.columns)
    print groups.apply(groupFunct)
```

**output**

```
     Control                       Recd_Date/Due_Date  \
0  2000-1703  2000-01-31 00:00:00,2000-02-29 00:00:00   
1  2000-1776  2000-01-02 00:00:00,2000-01-03 00:00:00   
2  2000-1983  2000-02-02 00:00:00,2000-02-03 00:00:00   

                                              Action  \
0                                    OC/OER/OPA/PMS/   
1  OC/ORA/OE/DCP/OC/ORA/ORO/PNC/FDA/OGROP/ORA/SE-...   
2                 FDA/OGROP/ORA/CE-FO/CHI-DO/CHI-CB/   

                      Signature/Requester  
0                        M WEBB,DATA CORP  
1                         G KAN,PALM POST  
2  M EGAN,BERNSTEIN LIEBHARD & LONDON LLP
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much!! In my original dataframe, type(df['Recd_Date/Due_Date'][i]) = datetime.datetime. So when I run your code on my dataframe, I get "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, datetime.datetime found"... I converted the ['Recd_Date/Due_Date'] column to str as 'df['Recd_Date/Due_Date'] = df['Recd_Date/Due_Date'].apply(str)' but still get the same error. Why? thanks..

Comment: I believe it is because the string.join(iterable) method only takes iterables with strings in it.  I edited the joinFunction method to convert all items to a string in the list comprehension section of it.  Your other columns also use non string/unicode types.  One more tip is you can use astype to convert a columns data type

Comment: Thanks very much for your help man! Can you pls help me to add two more conditions as i failed to add them to your code myself...1, For column 'Action' if its value ends with character '-', then joiner = "" else ",". 2, For column 'Signature/Requester' if its value ends with character '&', then joiner = " " else ",". Like this:

Comment: `if str(df.ix[i-1]['Action'])[-1] == '-':
           df.ix[i-1]['Action'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Action'])+str(df.ix[i]['Action'])
       else:
           df.ix[i-1]['Action'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Action'])+','+str(df.ix[i]['Action'])`

Comment: `if pd.isnull(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester']):
           df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])+str(df.ix[i]['Signature/Requester'])
       elif str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])[-1] == '&':
           df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])+' '+str(df.ix[i]['Signature/Requester'])
       else:
           df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'] = str(df.ix[i-1]['Signature/Requester'])+','+str(df.ix[i]['Signature/Requester'])` Thanks!!

Comment: I added some additional regex to clean up the joins, do you understand what is going on in the code?

Comment: Thanks! For the most part I understand but I don't really get the way you used `joiner.join()`. If each is notnull then each = each + joiner ( I only see you joined one each with a joiner); but how did you manage to get `If next_each is null: then returns each (joiner not added); else if next_each is not null: then returns each = each + joiner + next_each` work?? Thanks for your patience man, really appreciated! And btw `joiner.join()` doesn't seem to work when type(Recd_Date/Due_Date) becomes pandas.tslib.Timestamp ('NaN's becomes 'NaT's), any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: I used the re.sub lines to change something like "-/" into "-"/ with every condition.  Code should work with NaTs.  Want to post the creation of the dataframe so I can work with the dtypes you are using?  `df.to_dict('records')[:10]`

Comment: You can download the sample data from `https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w9f02hi9qoccud/foi_first2page%28from_freepdfconvert%29.xlsx` and `read_excel()`. Or from `https://www.dropbox.com/s/e22qyo3hzcr8ca4/foi_first2page%28from_adobe%29.xlsx` but after i used read_excel() i found the column names are embedded in row 36 and 37...Thanks!

Comment: df.to_dict('Recd_Date/Due_Date')[:10]
Out[22]: 
[{u'Action_Office': u'OC/OER/OPA/PMS/',
  u'Control_#': u'2000-1703',
  u'Recd_Date/Due_Date': Timestamp('2000-01-31 00:00:00', tz=None),
  u'Signature/Requester': u'M FRIEDMAN',
  u'Subject': u'DLECTRONIC DATA DUMP - PROD RECALLS, ALERTS &'},
 {u'Action_Office': nan,
  u'Control_#': nan,
  u'Recd_Date/Due_Date': Timestamp('2000-02-29 00:00:00', tz=None),
  u'Signature/Requester': u'DATA CONTROL CORP',
  u'Subject': u'WARNINGS, ENFORCEMENT RPTS'},
 ... ...

Comment: I meant I don't quite understand `s = joiner.join([str(each) for each in col if pd.notnull(each)])`, as for what i understand you joined 'each' with 'joiner' (e.g. `M EGAN` joined with `,`), but for joining `M EGAN`  `,` with next_each aka `BERNSTEIN LIEBHARD &`, it's the `pd.Series([joinFunc(g,col) for col in g.columns],index=g.columns)` that does the job right? And how did you make sure if next_each is null (e.g. there's nothing below `M EGAN`) then `M EGAN` does not join by joiner `,`? thanks!

Comment: Hi so I just used your dtypes and all the code that I posted is working.  As for how I removed the null values from the list look at this piece of code... `[str(each) for each in col if pd.notnull(each)]`  It is a list comprehension, and at the end there is an if statement removing null values.  The code returns all non null values from your column casted as strings in another list.

Comment: @ZJS very nice. Is there any way to do this with a generator instead of static variable? It would be more pythonic.