# Create groups/classes based on conditions within columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need help transforming my data so I can read through transaction data.

**Business Case**

I'm trying to group together some related transactions to create some groups or classes of events. This data set represents workers going out on various leaves of absence events. I want to create one class of leaves based on any transaction falling within 365 days of the leave event class. For charting trends, I want to number the classes so I get a sequence/pattern.

My code allows me to see when the very first event occurred, and it can identify when a new class starts, but it doesn't bucket each transaction into a class.

**Requirements:**

- Tag all rows based on what leave class they fall into.
- Number each Unique Leave Event. Using this example index 0 would be Unique Leave Event 2, index 1 would be Unique Leave Event 2, index 3 would be Unique Leave Event 2, AND index 4 would be Unique Leave Event 1, etc.

I added in a column for the desired output, labeled as "Desired Output". Note, there can be many more rows/events per person; and there can be many more people.

**Some Data**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Employee ID': ["100", "100", "100","100","200","200","200","300"],
        'Effective Date': ["2016-01-01","2015-06-05","2014-07-01","2013-01-01","2016-01-01","2015-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01"],
        'Desired Output': ["Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 1","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 1","Unique Leave Event 1"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee ID','Effective Date','Desired Output'])
```

**Some Code I've Tried**

```
df['Effective Date'] = df['Effective Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['EmplidShift'] = df['Employee ID'].shift(-1)
df['Effdt-Shift'] = df['Effective Date'].shift(-1)
df['Prior Row in Same Emplid Class'] = "No"
df['Effdt Diff'] = df['Effdt-Shift'] - df['Effective Date']
df['Effdt Diff'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['Effdt Diff'], unit='d') + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')).astype('timedelta64[D]')
df['Cumul. Count'] = df.groupby('Employee ID').cumcount()


df['Groupby'] = df.groupby('Employee ID')['Cumul. Count'].transform('max')
df['First Row Appears?'] = ""
df['First Row Appears?'][df['Cumul. Count'] == df['Groupby']] = "First Row"
df['Prior Row in Same Emplid Class'][ df['Employee ID'] == df['EmplidShift']]  = "Yes"

df['Prior Row in Same Emplid Class'][ df['Employee ID'] == df['EmplidShift']]  = "Yes"

df['Effdt > 1 Yr?'] = ""                                        
df['Effdt > 1 Yr?'][ ((df['Prior Row in Same Emplid Class'] == "Yes" ) & (df['Effdt Diff'] < -365))  ] = "Yes"

df['Unique Leave Event'] = ""
df['Unique Leave Event'][ (df['Effdt > 1 Yr?'] == "Yes") | (df['First Row Appears?'] == "First Row") ] = "Unique Leave Event" 

df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without having to loop or iterate through your dataframe.  Per [Wes McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964938/5066140) you can use `.apply()` with a groupBy object and define a function to apply to the groupby object.  If you use this with `.shift()` ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082596/5066140)) you can get your result without using any loops.

**Terse example:**

```
# Group by Employee ID
grouped = df.groupby("Employee ID")
# Define function 
def get_unique_events(group):
    # Convert to date and sort by date, like @Khris did
    group["Effective Date"] = pd.to_datetime(group["Effective Date"])
    group = group.sort_values("Effective Date")
    event_series = (group["Effective Date"] - group["Effective Date"].shift(1) > pd.Timedelta('365 days')).apply(lambda x: int(x)).cumsum()+1
    return event_series

event_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped.apply(get_unique_events).rename("Unique Event")).reset_index(level=0)
df = pd.merge(df, event_df[['Unique Event']], left_index=True, right_index=True)
df['Output'] = df['Unique Event'].apply(lambda x: "Unique Leave Event " + str(x))
df['Match'] = df['Desired Output'] == df['Output']

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Employee ID Effective Date        Desired Output  Unique Event  \
3         100     2013-01-01  Unique Leave Event 1             1
2         100     2014-07-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
1         100     2015-06-05  Unique Leave Event 2             2
0         100     2016-01-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
6         200     2013-01-01  Unique Leave Event 1             1
5         200     2015-01-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
4         200     2016-01-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
7         300        2014-01  Unique Leave Event 1             1

                 Output Match
3  Unique Leave Event 1  True
2  Unique Leave Event 2  True
1  Unique Leave Event 2  True
0  Unique Leave Event 2  True
6  Unique Leave Event 1  True
5  Unique Leave Event 2  True
4  Unique Leave Event 2  True
7  Unique Leave Event 1  True
```

**More verbose example for clarity:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Employee ID': ["100", "100", "100","100","200","200","200","300"],
        'Effective Date': ["2016-01-01","2015-06-05","2014-07-01","2013-01-01","2016-01-01","2015-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01"],
        'Desired Output': ["Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 1","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 1","Unique Leave Event 1"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee ID','Effective Date','Desired Output'])

# Group by Employee ID
grouped = df.groupby("Employee ID")

# Define a function to get the unique events
def get_unique_events(group):
     # Convert to date and sort by date, like @Khris did
    group["Effective Date"] = pd.to_datetime(group["Effective Date"])
    group = group.sort_values("Effective Date")
    # Define a series of booleans to determine whether the time between dates is over 365 days
    # Use .shift(1) to look back one row
    is_year = group["Effective Date"] - group["Effective Date"].shift(1) > pd.Timedelta('365 days')
    # Convert booleans to integers (0 for False, 1 for True)
    is_year_int = is_year.apply(lambda x: int(x))    
    # Use the cumulative sum function in pandas to get the cumulative adjustment from the first date.
    # Add one to start the first event as 1 instead of 0
    event_series = is_year_int.cumsum() + 1
    return event_series

# Run function on df and put results into a new dataframe
# Convert Employee ID back from an index to a column with .reset_index(level=0)
event_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped.apply(get_unique_events).rename("Unique Event")).reset_index(level=0)

# Merge the dataframes
df = pd.merge(df, event_df[['Unique Event']], left_index=True, right_index=True)

# Add string to match desired format
df['Output'] = df['Unique Event'].apply(lambda x: "Unique Leave Event " + str(x))

# Check to see if output matches desired output
df['Match'] = df['Desired Output'] == df['Output']

print(df)
```

**You get the same output:**

```
  Employee ID Effective Date        Desired Output  Unique Event  \
3         100     2013-01-01  Unique Leave Event 1             1
2         100     2014-07-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
1         100     2015-06-05  Unique Leave Event 2             2
0         100     2016-01-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
6         200     2013-01-01  Unique Leave Event 1             1
5         200     2015-01-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
4         200     2016-01-01  Unique Leave Event 2             2
7         300        2014-01  Unique Leave Event 1             1

                 Output Match
3  Unique Leave Event 1  True
2  Unique Leave Event 2  True
1  Unique Leave Event 2  True
0  Unique Leave Event 2  True
6  Unique Leave Event 1  True
5  Unique Leave Event 2  True
4  Unique Leave Event 2  True
7  Unique Leave Event 1  True
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution. The only danger could lie in the `merge` if OP is using really huge dataframes, but judging from the content of the data that's unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit clunky but it yields the right output at least for your small example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Employee ID': ["100", "100", "100","100","200","200","200","300"],
        'Effective Date': ["2016-01-01","2015-06-05","2014-07-01","2013-01-01","2016-01-01","2015-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01"],
        'Desired Output': ["Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 1","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 2","Unique Leave Event 1","Unique Leave Event 1"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee ID','Effective Date','Desired Output'])

df["Effective Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Effective Date"])
df = df.sort_values(["Employee ID","Effective Date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

for i,_ in df.iterrows():
  df.ix[0,"Result"] = "Unique Leave Event 1"
  if i < len(df)-1:
    if df.ix[i+1,"Employee ID"] == df.ix[i,"Employee ID"]:
      if df.ix[i+1,"Effective Date"] - df.ix[i,"Effective Date"] > pd.Timedelta('365 days'):
        df.ix[i+1,"Result"] = "Unique Leave Event " + str(int(df.ix[i,"Result"].split()[-1])+1)
      else:
        df.ix[i+1,"Result"] = df.ix[i,"Result"]
    else:
      df.ix[i+1,"Result"] = "Unique Leave Event 1"
```

Note that this code assumes that the first row always contains the string `Unique Leave Event 1`.

EDIT: Some explanation.

First I convert the dates to datetime format and then reorder the dataframe such that the dates for every Employee ID are ascending.

Then I iterate over the rows of the frame using the built-int iterator `iterrows`. The `_` in `for i,_` is merely a placeholder for the second variable I do not use because the iterator gives back both row numbers and rows, I only need the numbers here.

In the iterator I'm doing row-wise comparisons so by default I fill in the first row by hand and then assign to the `i+1`-th row. I do it like this because I know the value of the first row but not the value of the last row. Then I compare the `i+1`-th row with the `i`-th row within an `if`-safeguard because `i+1` would give an index-error on the last iteration.

In the loop I first check if the `Employee ID` has changed between the two rows. If it has not then I compare the dates of the two rows and see if they are apart more than 365 days. If this is the case I read the string `"Unique Leave Event X"` from the `i`-th row, increase the number by one and write it in the `i+1`-row. If the dates are closer I just copy the string from the previous row.

If the `Employee ID` does change on the other hand I just write `"Unique Leave Event 1"` to start over.

Note 1: `iterrows()` has no options to set so I can't iterate only over a subset.

Note 2: Always iterate using one of the built-in iterators and only iterate if you can't solve the problem otherwise.

Note 3: When assigning values in an iteration always use `ix`, `loc`, or `iloc`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide some commentary on how you did this?

Comment: Hi, and sorry for the long wait, I only comment here from work and we had a three-day weekend. I will add some comment now.