# How to trim lines in pandas dataframe by timestamp diff

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe including route coordinates and timestamp per random time intervals (from 1 to 50 seconds) as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h72t4.png) dataframe sample. I am looking for a way to trim the dataset in a way to keep only time differences greater then or equal to 30 seconds.

For example if the time stamp by index is like the following:

- [0] 2017-03-27 06:52:30
- [1] 2017-03-27 06:52:32
- [2] 2017-03-27 06:52:45
- [3] 2017-03-27 06:52:59
- [4] 2017-03-27 06:53:02
- [5] 2017-03-27 06:53:32
- [...] ......

Idealy I would like to keep only:

- [0] 2017-03-27 06:52:30
- [4] 2017-03-27 06:53:02
- [5] 2017-03-27 06:53:32
- [...] ......

Event a hint would be helpful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': [Timestamp('2017-03-27 06:52:30'),
                 Timestamp('2017-03-27 06:52:32'),
                 Timestamp('2017-03-27 06:52:45'),
                 Timestamp('2017-03-27 06:52:59'),
                 Timestamp('2017-03-27 06:53:02'),
                 Timestamp('2017-03-27 06:53:32')]
    })
```

I use a generator to sift through and identify when delta time has exceeded some threshold and returns the indices.

```
def f(s, thresh):
    cur = None
    for i, v in s.iteritems():
        if (cur is None) or (v - cur >= thresh):
            yield i
            cur = v


df.loc[list(f(df.date, pd.to_timedelta(30, 's')))]

                 date
0 2017-03-27 06:52:30
4 2017-03-27 06:53:02
5 2017-03-27 06:53:32
```

Comment: this is clever !

Comment: Thank you very much! It worded as expected!

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided the data frame, let's say your column name is `time`.
You could do: `df.time.shift(1) - df.time`. This will give you a column of the differences. Now you can use the index and now the new column to filter through the `time` column.

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081878/get-previous-rows-value-and-calculate-new-column-pandas-python) is not a duplicate, but may be used for the application of this `shift` method.

This is a big hint to how I would approach it. Hope it helps!

P.s. Do provide the full data frame for future reference, so that the code can be clearly seen and referenced in reply.