# How to calculate rows which reference previous row with conditions in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas dataframe, is it possible to calculate rows which need previous value without actual iterate each row?
For example:

```
        for i in range(1, len(price)):
            if price.index[i] in trade_date_index_list:
                gross_pnl.iat[i, 0] = price.iloc[i]['A'] + price.iloc[i]['B']
            else:
                gross_pnl.iat[i, 0] = gross_pnl.iat[i - 1, 0] + price.iloc[i]['C']
```

Is there a way to avoid iterating each row? I think the tricky part is that to calculate the next row, I need to have the value in current row which is determined by the if condition.
Thank you.

Comment: Iterating each row explicitly is almost never a good idea. can you give an example df and the expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082596/131187 may be what you want.