# Replace NaNs with values from X rows earlier or later in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe in which each row represents a consecutive day and the column represents total electricity consumption. There are some NaN values where data is missing:

```
     ELECTRICITY
0    10
1    15
2    17
3    12
4    15
5    16
6    22
7    8
8    NaN
9    16
10   13
```

Because electricity consumption in this sample is mostly affected by day of the week, I want to replace all NaNs with the value from 7 rows earlier or later.

I have investigated the following with no success:

1. fillna: only allows me to replace with a specific value or immediately adjacent values
2. interpolate: only allows me to replace with an average of immediately adjacent values
3. replace: seems to allow conditional replacements with set values

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you provide a more complete data example?  Is there a date column to your data that can be leveraged or is the data always assumed to be in order?  Also you say you want to replace the value "from 7 rows earlier or later".  In what cases would you want the value from 7 days earlier and in what cases from 7 days later?  Providing what you expect the output to be for the `NaN` in the data you provide would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081878/get-previous-rows-value-and-calculate-new-column-pandas-python

Comment: @vealkind Thanks for the clarifying questions. I tried to simplify the example as much as possible so that my dataset's idiosyncrasies don't make the question irrelevant for others - maybe I went too far! Below are the requested clarifications. As I am new to SO, please advise me if I should rather update the question:
(1) Is there a date column: the index is a DatetimeIndex with hourly times
(2) When 7 rows earlier / later: replace with 7 rows earlier if 7 rows earlier is not NaN, else 7 days later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fillna` and `shift`

```
df.fillna(df.shift(7))

    ELECTRICITY
0          10.0
1          15.0
2          17.0
3          12.0
4          15.0
5          16.0
6          22.0
7           8.0
8          15.0
9          16.0
10         13.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you.