# Python dataframe: create column with running formula based on values in one row prior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

I have dataframe `df` with daily stock market for 10 years having columns `Date`, `Open`, `Close`.

I want to calculate the change between any two consecutive values (in `Close`) as a ratio of the previous value.

For example, in **photo below**, first entry (-0.0002) for `Interday_return` is calculated as = (43.06-43.07)/43.07.
Similarly the next value 0.0046 is calculated as = (43.26-43.06)/43.06.
And so on..

I am able to create a new column `Interday_Close_change` which is basically the difference between each 2 consecutive rows using this code (ie.. finding the numerator of the above mentioned fraction). However, I dont know how to divide any element in `Interday_Close_change` by value in the preceding row and get a new column `Interday_return`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['Interday_Close_change'] = df['Close'].astype(float).diff()
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081878/get-previous-rows-value-and-calculate-new-column-pandas-python answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```py
df['Interday_Close_change'] = df['Close'].pct_change().fillna('')
```

Sample input:

```
       Date   Open  Close
0  1/2/2018  42.54  43.07
1  1/3/2018  43.13  43.06
2  1/4/2018  43.14  43.26
3  1/5/2018  43.36  43.75
```

Sample output:

```
       Date   Open  Close Interday_Close_change
0  1/2/2018  42.54  43.07
1  1/3/2018  43.13  43.06             -0.000232
2  1/4/2018  43.14  43.26              0.004645
3  1/5/2018  43.36  43.75              0.011327
```

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) on `pct_change`.

Comment: @Sinha Do you need any additional help with your question?